# Can not fix an element right to a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem**: `innerHTML` of an elements with className `deleting` does not want to display fixed on the screen, right from the rectangle elements `text-block`. If we zoom screen - `deleting.innerHTML` will be stay on their positions on os X, but must stay with `text-block` elements. I have already sum `deleting` 's positon with `pageXOffset`, but it does not help in width zooming.

```js
   function createPoindetDel(text) {

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {

     var textCoords = text[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 

     var pointDel = document.createElement('p');
    pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
    pointDel.className = 'deleting';
    pointDel.style.cssText = 'position:absolute; float:right; margin:0px; display:inline; cursor:pointer;';

      pointDel.style.top = textCoords.top + pageYOffset + 'px';
    pointDel.style.left = textCoords.right + pageXOffset + 'px';
    
    text[i].appendChild(pointDel);

  }
  
  return pointDel;
   }

   function getDelete() {

    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
        
    createPoindetDel(text); 

    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('deleting');
    var tech = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++ ) {
     var index = j;
     tech[j] = (function () { 
    p[index].addEventListener( 'click', function() {text[index].remove()} );
      p[index].addEventListener( 'click', function() {p[index].remove()} );
     })();
    }
   }

getDelete();
```

```css
  .text-block {
   max-width: 500px;
   height: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
   background-color: #EDF5E1;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .text-block span {
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color:  #111;
   margin-top: 0;
  }

  .text-block p {
   font-size:  15px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   color: #111;

  }
```

```html
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make it complicated. Just set `.text-block` `position:relative` and then set appropriate fixed absolute position of `.deleting` as child element relative to parent `.text-block`. All via styles..

```js
function createPoindetDel(text) {

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {

     var textCoords = text[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 

     var pointDel = document.createElement('p');
    pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
    pointDel.className = 'deleting';
    text[i].appendChild(pointDel);

  }
  
  return pointDel;
   }

   function getDelete() {

    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
        
    createPoindetDel(text); 

    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('deleting');
    var tech = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++ ) {
     var index = j;
     tech[j] = (function () { 
    p[index].addEventListener( 'click', function() {text[index].remove()} );
      p[index].addEventListener( 'click', function() {p[index].remove()} );
     })();
    }
   }

getDelete();
```

```css
.text-block {
   max-width: 500px;
   height: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
   background-color: #EDF5E1;
   margin-bottom: 0;
    position:relative;
  }

  .text-block span {
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color:  #111;
   margin-top: 0;
  }

  .text-block p {
   font-size:  15px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   color: #111;

  }
  .deleting {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    display:inline;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
```